# Kloxo apache config template

Tags: apache, templates, kloxo

I'm using **Kloxo** control panel. And if an account is created through kloxo, It creates a domain config includes virtual host of the created domains and another strings in path : 
**/home/apache/conf/domains/$domain.conf**

My question is : 
How can i configure this config template and modify it, I want this modifications to be applied in new create accounts accounts.

Like the ones which exists in **cPanel** control panel in **/var/cpanel/templates/apache2/**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kloxo does not use templates for Apache or Lighttpd. You must edit the PHP file which generates vhost configuration files and customize it to your needs.

```
/usr/local/lxlabs/kloxo/httpdocs/lib/domain/web/driver/web__apachelib.php
```

Just keep in mind the file will be overwritten everytime you update the panel.